# Postgres recursive queries and window functions to produce tree from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Let's say I have the following data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ORDERS(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  category TEXT,
  subcategory TEXT,
  description TEXT
);

INSERT INTO TABLE ORDERS VALUES
(1001, "CAT1"   "SUBCAT1"   "DESC1"),
(1002, "CAT1"   "SUBCAT1"   "DESC2"),
(1003, "CAT1"   "SUBCAT2"   "DESC3"),
(1004, "CAT1"   "SUBCAT2"   "DESC4"),
(1005, "CAT1"   "SUBCAT2"   "DESC5"),
(1006, "CAT2"   "SUBCAT3"   "DESC6"),
(1007, "CAT2"   "SUBCAT3"   "DESC7"),
(1008, "CAT2"   "SUBCAT4"   "DESC8"),
```

I got the request to produce a table with a single column in which categories and subcategories appear arranged like this.

```
result
-------------
CAT1
  -> SUBCAT1
    -> DESC1
    -> DESC2
    -> DESC3
  -> SUBCAT2
    -> DESC4
    -> DESC5
CAT2
  -> SUBCAT3
    -> DESC6
    -> DESC7
  -> SUBCAT4
    -> DESC8
```

I don't understand how to complete the task with the requirements established by my client (especially the first one). These are:

- I should use two new columns:

  - `parent`: to reference the parent level category.
  - `seq_orders`: to build a sequence
- I should use window functions and a recursive query to build the tree-like column

I'm hoping that someone who sees this from the outside could provide some help.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

It's necessary to (somehow) follow this process as requested by the client:

1. Create column `parent` to refer to the higher level category. Higher-level categories will have this field as null.
2. Create a sequence called `seq_orders` that starts with 1 and increases by one unit.
3. Insert into the table orders the different levels of level 1 (category field) and level 2 (subcategory field) using the above sequence to assign the different `id`s. In Level 2 and Level 3 the `parent` field has to point to the corresponding higher level category.
4. Remove the redundant fields category and subcategory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't want a recursive CTE.  You want to unpivot the data and add in rows for each level.  This looks like:

```
select x.which
from ((select '    -> ' || o.description as which, array[o.category, o.subcategory, o.description] as ord
       from orders o
       group by o.category, o.subcategory, o.description
      ) union all
      (select '  -> ' || o.subcategory, array[o.category, o.subcategory]
       from orders o
       group by o.category, o.subcategory
      ) union all
      (select o.category, array[o.category]
       from orders o
       group by o.category
      )
     ) x
order by ord;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09533d857cf741cba1b773d1126a2761) is a recursive CTE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It gives the desired result. However, I have to fulfill the mentioned requirements from the client. As described: 1) creating the `parent` column to store references pointing to the categories, subcategories, and descriptions; 2) use another column as a sequence to enumerate the items. There are two more that I missed. I'll add them to the question.

Comment: @CarlosDavila . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, I would suggest asking it as a *new* question.